# Is this pot too big for a jade plant?

Tags: containers, jade

I have this jade plant that is in need of a bigger pot. I have this clay pot and I was wondering if it was too big, I've heard that if a small plant is in a big pot it might die. Here's a picture of the jade in its current pot compared to the clay one. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your worry is well placed - the empty pot is a bit too large for such a small plant. Find one that's 1-2 sizes bigger than the pot it currently occupies instead, somewhere between the two pot sizes you have there. This Q & A might be helpful [Transfering a plant to a larger pot](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/transfering-a-plant-to-a-larger-pot?rq=1)

Comment: I'll never understand the perpetuation of this "small pot" myth. The biggest, healthiest jade plants I've ever seen were planted in the ground, completely unfettered by a pot of any sort. Certainly not root bound in any way. Is there a scientific journal you can point me to that supports this notion?

Comment: @TimNevins But surely you are aware that plants growing in open ground is nothing like plants growing in pots because the environment is not closed in the ground, unlike in a pot, and potting soil is a different medium from that found in the ground? There's plenty of info on the web on this subject but here's one http://northcoastgardening.com/2008/11/garden-qa-why-transplant-into-larger-pots-in-stages/ and here https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=864

Comment: Neither source cites a single scientific expert. While Genevieve may be a nice person, she's a landscape designer, not a scientist as far as I can discover. The other article is unattributed. There is also plenty of info on the web stating the earth is flat. I see two problems here; confusing correlation with causation and assuming personal observations are scientific truths. How does the plant know if it's in a pot or in the ground? It's not the plant or the pot, it's how you manage the environmental stimuli.

Comment: I disagree, both with your dismissing one source and your stance on size of pot  - the RHS is a very reliable source, unlike the blog, although she's not saying anything different, by and large. But we will agree to disagree if you like, since  you don't believe the RHS is a source to be taken seriously. Probably there is other scientific evidence somewhere or other, but  I don't need convincing on this  subject, both from what I was taught and from experience, and the fact that the RHS IS a reliable source of scientific experiment and is a teaching body - you do, so maybe you have the time