# Tomato plants with light spots on the leaves

Tags: leaves, tomatoes, seedlings

I’m new to growing tomatoes and noticed these spots. I’m not sure if it’s due to watering issues, a fungus, or something else.

I am currently growing them inside and place them in the window when the suns out and substitute with grow lights when it is not. I water enough to keep the soil moist and have ensure the pots drain well.

[image]

Comment: Not part of the question, but are those seedlings/cuttings in one communal pot? If so, I would separate them soon, before the roots get all tangled up.

Comment: Hi, yes they are seedling. Thank you for the advice I will definitely be moving them to a new pot tomorrow.

Comment: Pots. Plural. Each seedling should get an individual pot. Not too large for now, move them to larger pots as they grow up. [The pot size needs to match the plant size.](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/transfering-a-plant-to-a-larger-pot)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the info. Will definitely move them to an individual pot that is a suitable size for each plant tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem.  Plants have get spots easily, especially seedlings. The one leaf looks like possible physical damage on the very end, maybe laying against something.  Some of the spots might be from water on the leaves.   Other than that plants get spots.  Plants are just like us.  We are all not perfect, some of us have freckles others have moles.  It does not make us defective, jut unique.  Even our scars do not make us defective.  Plants are just like us.